# Can the bitstreams be put into a $1$ to $1$ correspondence with themselves?

Tags: logic, cardinals

Cantors diagonal argument tells us that there are uncountably many bisteams. That is to say that a set of all bitstreams cannot be put into a 1 to 1 correspondence with the natural numbers, enumerated for short.

The proof is appears simple. If we could enumerate the bitstreams, then we could generate a list as follows:

\begin{align}
\text{Naturals}&&\text{Bitstreams}\\
0&&\color{red}{0}000\dots\\
1&&0\color{red}{1}00\dots\\
2&&10\color{red}{0}0\dots\\
3&&110\color{red}{0}\dots\\
\end{align}

Take the diagonal of the bitstreams in this list and "flip" each bit. The concatenation of every flipped bit $\color{red}{1011\dots}$ would itself be a bitstream and not in the list. Therefore the assumption that we could enumerate the bitstreams was a false one.

---

Can we repeat this proof using the bitsreams themselves instead of trying to make a correspondence with the natural numbers?

\begin{equation}\newcommand\mapsfrom{\mathrel{\reflectbox{\ensuremath{\mapsto}}}}
\text{bitstreams}\mapsto\text{bitstreams}
\end{equation}

That is, can we replace each natural number on the left with the bitstream on the right, and follow the same procedure as before, to show that the bitstreams cannot be put into a 1 to 1 correspondence with themselves?

Comment: Since bitstreams can of course be put in $1$-to-$1$ correspondence with themselves, the answer is no. There are uncountably many bit streams so there is no diagonal available.

Comment: Every set can trivially be put into one-to-one correspondence with itself via the identity function.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I don't understand why there would be no diagonal available. Why does a set being uncountable prevent this, if so, why were we able to find a diagonal in Cantor's argument when the set was also uncountable?

Comment: For there to be a diagonal the number of rows in the table has to be equal to the number of columns. For the enumeration using natural numbers there are countably infinitely many of both. If you try to run the same argument using bitstreams there are still only countably many bits in each bitstream (columns) but uncountably many bitstreams (rows).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Can you put this into an answer please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elaborating on my comments: I think you haven't asked the question you intended to ask. Of course the set of bitstreams can be put into $1$-to-$1$ correspondence with themselves: you send every bitstream to itself. The question I think you're asking is where the proof of Cantor's theorem fails when you try to repeat it in this situation.

Where it fails is that there is no "diagonal." For there to be a diagonal the number of rows in the table has to be equal to the number of columns. For the enumeration using natural numbers there are countably infinitely many of both. If you try to run the same argument using bitstreams there are still only countably many bits in each bitstream (columns) but uncountably many bitstreams (rows). So you'll find that you can write down a bitstream which is different from any countable collection of bitstreams (this is equivalent to the set of bitstreams being uncountable), but you can't say any more than that.

Comment: Thanks, it's sometimes hard to formulate a question when you are reasoning from contradiction as I was.

Comment: @user400188: yes, this is one reason why it's good to avoid contradiction if possible. It's unnecessary to phrase Cantor's theorem as a proof by contradiction. It's a proof that there exists no surjection (so in particular no bijection) $\mathbb{N} \to 2^{\mathbb{N}}$, and the proof argues that any map $f : \mathbb{N} \to 2^{\mathbb{N}}$ misses at least one element by constructing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Any set, no matter the cardinality, can always be put in a one-to-one correspondence with itself, using the bijection $f(x)=x$.